# Uncaught TypeError: cannot set property 'onClick' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I was working on an HTML music creator. I am getting an error every time I run a JavaScript function to add an `onClick` attribute to every `td` element starting from the eighth element of the `td` tags. I get the error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: cannot set property 'onClick' of undefined."

Here is my JavaScript:

```
function addOnclick() {
    var num = 1;
    var note = 0;
    i = 8;
    while (i < (17 * 12) + 8 + 1) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("td")[i].onClick = "switchNote(" + num + ", " + note + ")";
        if (i == 25 || i == 42 || i == 59 || i == 76 || i == 81 || i == 98 || i == 115 || i == 132 || i == 149 || i == 166 || i == 183 || i == 200 || i == 217) {
            note = note + 1;
            num = 1;
        }
        i = i + 1;
        num = num + 1;
        console.log("working");
    }
}
```

If you have any idea, please help!

Thanks,
*Tendel T.*

Comment: What is `document.getElementsByTagName("td").length`? And why aren't you using that in your `while` condition instead of `(17 * 12) + 8 + 1`? (Or, better, creating a variable `var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td")` before the loop instead of calling `.getElementsByTagName()` on every iteration.)

Comment: ^that and you should use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of `onclick`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of assigning value to `OnClick` you should use `setAttribute` and check whether element has been defined or not as shown below:

```
function addOnclick() {
    function addOnclick() {
        var num = 1;
        var note = 0;
        i = 8;
        while (i < (17 * 12) + 8 + 1) {
            var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[i];
            if (elem)
            {
                elem.setAttribute('onclick', "switchNote(" + num + ", " + note + ")")
            }

            if (i == 25 || i == 42 || i == 59 || i == 76 || i == 81 || i == 98 || i == 115 || i == 132 || i == 149 || i == 166 || i == 183 || i == 200 || i == 217) {
                note = note + 1;
                num = 1;
            }
            i = i + 1;
            num = num + 1;
            console.log("working");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the OP's code gives the error `cannot set property 'onClick' of undefined`, won't your suggestion give essentially the same error about not being able to call the `.setAttribute()` method of undefined?

Comment: @TendelT.: Don't forget to mark it as an answer if it helped. So that other users facing the same problem could get solution.

Answer (score 1):

Two things,

1. You need to check if the element exists (difficult to tell without your markup).

try something like

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[i];
element && element.onclick = function(){
    switchNote( num, note )
};
```

2. Value of an onclick handler cannot be a string, it has to be a function.

Comment: Testing if the element exists *inside* the loop seems a bit pointless, because as soon as `i` reaches a high enough value that the corresponding element doesn't exist *none* of the higher indexed elements will exist either. So better to just exit the loop or fix the loop condition.

Comment: @nnnnnn true, but without markup or details of OP's specific context, it is difficult to tell if the loop is indeed a problem.